# PyVisa on OSX Mavericks not recognizing USB 6255

Tags: python, labview, visa

After following the pyvisa documentation very carefully, I'm unable to communicate with my NI USB 6255 via python. I'm using the correct distribution of python (the 32bit one), and I'm in a virtualenv so I don't screw up my normal one.

after creating a `ResourceManager()` object called `rm`, ensuring that my daq is plugged in and on, I get the following:

```
>>> rm
    <ResourceManager(<VisaLibrary('/Library/Frameworks/visa.framework/visa')>)>
>>> rm.list_resources()
    (u'ASRL1::INSTR', u'ASRL2::INSTR', u'ASRL3::INSTR')
```

However, on a Macbook these are the two bluetooth ports and then my phone connected via usb.

In NIVisaIC, my DAQ comes up as a USB RAW resource, but I'm unable to read/query it due to an "I/O Error".

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you were setting up PyVISA you may have only installed NI-VISA on your system. You probably need NI DAQmx Base as well.  You also need to know if the NI USB 6255 is compatible with the DAQmx Base driver.

So, check for DAQmx Base and compatibility with the 6255.

Here's the link to the latest Mac OS X DAQmx Base download.
http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-base-3.7/4272/en/

Answer (score 0):

The USB-6255 is not supported on Mac OS X, so VISA will not be able to detect it. The list of supported hardware and features is in the [DAQmx Base readme](http://ftp.ni.com/support/softlib//multifunction_daq/nidaqmxbase/3.7/Mac%20OS%20X/ReadMe.rtf). A similar device that might match your requirements is the [USB-6212](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/207096): [image]

> **NI-DAQmx Base 3.7 readme**
>   
> http://ftp.ni.com/support/softlib//multifunction_daq/nidaqmxbase/3.7/Mac%20OS%20X/ReadMe.rtf
>
> **NI USB-6218**
>   
> http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/207096